# Programmatically set values of jsoup parsed webpage

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to set value to the text field of a web page programmatically. I parsed the page using JSOUP and got to know about the input text fields. I used the following code:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("input[type=text]");
 for (Iterator<Element> iterator = elements.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
 {
     Element element = iterator.next();
     System.out.println(element);
     System.out.println(elements.attr("name"));
     System.out.println(elements.attr("value"));
 }
```

This code is working fine and since the value is not yet set on the webpage it is showing blank for elements.attr("value"). Is there any possibility to set elements.attr("value") programmatically? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a job for a tool like Selenium rather than jsoup. Using selenium you can navigate to the page you require, find the element in the page (e.g. form) and set its value. Jsoup can grab the source of the page, and filter out the elements you want but Im not sure how you can make any additions to the page using jsoup alone.

Answer (score 1):

Changes you make in your Jsoup-parsed objects are not reflected on the page as these objects have no connection to the page code which is displayed in browser.

You should look towards AJAX to set a value from a Java app on a web page. Make an asynchronous call from your page to your app and use JavaScript to set the values you need on callback.